# cannot insert record incorrect integer vaue

Tags: mysql, audit-logging

Mysql: When I execute the below mentioned things I facе

> Incorrect integer value: ' . 42 . ' for column 'user_id' at row 1)

this error and can't insert the records why is this happening so?

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
       `uid` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `uname` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
         `urole` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
         `udesig` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    `usalary` INT(6) NOT NULL

     );

CREATE TABLE `audit_trail_test` (
         `_id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `_group_id` INT(5) NOT NULL,
         `uid` INT NOT NULL,
           `uname` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
         `urole` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
         `udesig` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
         `usalary` INT(6) NOT NULL

     );
CREATE TABLE `audit_trail_revisions` (
         `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
         `time` DATETIME NOT NULL
     );

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE create_revision_record()
     BEGIN
        IF @group_id IS NULL THEN
             INSERT INTO `audit_trail_revisions`
                 (user_id, `time`)
                     VALUES
                 (@user_id, @time);
            SET @group_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        END IF;
     END;


     CREATE TRIGGER `test_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `test`
         FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
             CALL create_revision_record();
             INSERT INTO `audit_trail_test`
                 (
                     uid,
                     uname,
     urole,
     udesig,
     usalary,
                     _group_id
                 )
            VALUES
                 (
                     NEW.uid,
                     NEW.uname,
     NEW.urole,
     NEW.udesig,
     NEW.usalary,
                     @group_id
                );
         END;
     $$

CREATE TRIGGER `test_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `test`
         FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
             CALL create_revision_record();
             INSERT INTO `audit_trail_test`
                 (
                     uid,
                     uname,
     urole,
     udesig,
     usalary ,
                    _group_id
                 )
             VALUES
                 (
                     NEW.uid,
                     NEW.uname,
     NEW.urole,
     NEW.udesig,
     NEW.usalary,
                     @group_id
                 );
         END;
     $$

DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE delete_revision_record()
     BEGIN
         IF @group_id IS  NULL THEN
             INSERT INTO `audit_trail_revisions`
                 (user_id, `time`)
                     VALUES
                 (@user_id, @time);
             SET @group_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        END IF;
     END;

 CREATE TRIGGER `test_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `test`
         FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
             CALL delete_revision_record();
             DELETE FROM `audit_trail_test` WHERE uid=_id;
        END;
     $$

query : 1.SET @user_id = ' . 42 . ', @time = NOW();
query : 2.insert into test(uname,urole,udesig,usalary) values('abc','cba','bac',10000);
```

Comment: The `audit_trail_revisions` table has a `user_id` column which was defined as integer.  Does the value `. 42 .` look like an integer to you?  By the way, please format your question so it is readable.

Comment: but 42 is a integer right

Comment: Yes...but you're trying to insert a _string_, not an integer, which has other characters besides digits.  You can't do that.  What prompted you to insert `. 42 .`?  Maybe if you can answer this, we can give you more feedback.

Comment: Got the issue thankyou tim